# Typescript element in array not accessible

Tags: arrays, typescript

This seems to be a very awkward problem:

I am accessing my `modal.service.ts` using the following code:
`this.modalService.add('test');`

My `modal.service.ts` looks like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {
    private modals: any[] = [];

    add(modal: any) {
        // add modal to array of active modals
        this.modals.push(modal);
    }

    remove(id: string) {
        // remove modal from array of active modals
        this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
    }

    open(id: string) {
        // open modal specified by id
        const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === id);
        console.log(this.modals)
        console.log(this.modals[0])
        //modal.open();
    }

    close(id: string) {
        // close modal specified by id
        const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === id);
        modal.close();
    }
}
```

Why does `console.log(this.modals[0])` give me `undefined` when `this.modals` gives me an output of the array with 'test' being at pos 0?

This is the console output:
[image: Console Output]

Comment: *when this.modals gives me an output of the array with 'test' being at pos 0?* Where? Can you post a screenshot

Comment: Please find a screenshot attached.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: if u log array with item it would be look like ["test"], you have in consolo []. this is wierd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a problem with (or feature of) browser's `console`. It shows that `0`th element of `this.modals` is "test" because at the moment of inspecting it is. But at the moment of executing it is empty.

```
{
  const anArray = [];
  console.log(anArray);
  console.log(anArray[0]);
  anArray.push("foo");
}
// Browser's output:
// >>> []  <-- But expanded it will show [0: "foo"].
// >>> undefined

{
  const anArray = [];
  anArray.push("foo");
  console.log(anArray);
  console.log(anArray[0]);
}
// Browser's output:
// >>> ["foo"]  <-- See. Already pre-filled on display.
// >>> foo
```

So what you actually have is a race condition. Your `this.modals` is filled after `open` is called.

Comment: I see, thanks. Tough to debug if you don't know that Chrome is logging asynchronously.
What would be the best approach to wait for it to not be `undefined`?
Any chance using `Promises`?

Comment: I do not know what other part of code looks like and I am not an expert on Angular. So I can't help much. The right thing would be to make sure that `add` gets called before `open`. If you can't guarantee then it is going to be complicated. You can try to play with async and/or promises. Other option would be to have `pendingModalOpenings`. Which would be filled on `open` if modal does not exist yet. And then in `open` you would check if there is anything waiting in `pendingModalOpenings` and open just added modal if needed.